# Join table more than one id from the joined table

Tags: mysql, sql, join

i have tables like this

**Employee**

```
id  | employee |
1   | gorg     |
2   | ocle     |
3   | oke      |
```

**Task**

```
id  | employeeId1 | employeeId2
1   |  1          |    1
2   |  3          |    2
```

**Query**

```
SELECT a.employeeId1, 
       b.employee as employee1, 
       a.employeeId2, 
       c.employee as employee2, 
FROM `Task` a 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Employee b on a.employeeId1 = b.id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Employee c on a.employeeId2 = c.id
```

**Result**

```
id  | employeeId1 | employee1  |  employeeId2 | employee2
1   |  1          |    gorg    |    1         |   gorg
2   |  3          |    oke     |    2         |   ocle
```

In my query, i have to join Employee table with Task to get Employee's name. In the the first join, i joined with Employee Table to get Employee name for employeeId1, but in the next column of my task, there is another id for employee, so i joined the Employee again to get Employee's name in employeeId2.

Is there any better ways to prevent join the same table from the first joined table ?

Comment: No, there is no better way.

Comment: I don't think there is a better alternative. You have to `JOIN` twice.

Comment: One way you could potentially do it is get rid of the second column and join via another table (call it "employee_task" for instace) in a many-to-many relation.

Comment: You could fire all the employees.  Then you would only need to join once.

Comment: thanks for the answer